# Intercepting/Decorating Activities in Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, .net, aop, workflow-foundation-4

Does Windows Workflow Foundation offer a way to intercept or decorate activities for purposes such as logging? For example to create logs for every activity entry and exit point (ideally including the activity name) without modifying all the existing project code.

For example, I have a workflow with a single activity that prints "Hello world". Without making modification to the XAML file I would like to capture the entry and exit of the activity. I would like to print "Entering Hello World Activity" before entering the activity and after the activity has printed "Hello World", I would like to print "Completed Hello World Activity".

Does Windows Workflow offer a mechanism for hooking into entry and exit of an activity?

---

@Richard210363 has already added to the comments that this feature is supported by Windows Workflow Foundation - please can the users who chose to close this question consider reversing their decision as the question clearly has a very specific answer using the framework in question?

Comment: not sure about the Windows Workflow framework, but AOP is not supported out-of-the-box with .net.  you will need to look into MS Unity, or PostSharp, etc. but I doubt it will be turnkey solution and will require work (adding attributes if you are using postsharp, or coding methodologies via other solutions)

Comment: Say i have a workflow xaml with one activity which prints "Hello world". Now without making modification of the XAML file, i want to print "Entering Hello World Activity" before entering into the activity. After Printing "Hello World", I should be able to print "Completed Hello World Activity". Basically AOP solves this use case.

Comment: Have a look at the workflow TrackingParticipant class.  You attach this to a workflow before running.  _workflowApplication.Extensions.Add(TrackingParticipant); It acts across all Activities in the workflow similar to AOP in scope.  It emits information about the entry and exit of activities.  You should inherit from TrackingParticipant and override the Track method:  protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout).  Then cast TrackingRecord to ActivityStateRecord.  The activity name is then ActivityStateRecord..Activity.Name

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205426(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This question is perfectly reasonable in terms of WWF and has a simple answer please take off hold

Comment: @Richard210363 - got this one reopened - do you want to add the answer?

Comment: I've added the cleaned up answer below. Ta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the workflow TrackingParticipant class.

It acts across all Activities in the workflow similar to AOP in scope.

It emits information about the entry and exit of activities.

Create a class that inherits from TrackingParticipant and override the Track method:

```
protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        ActivityStateRecord activityStateRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;
        string CurrentActivityName = activityStateRecord.Activity.Name,
    }
```

Then attach your tracking class to the workflow before it runs.

```
_workflowApplication.Extensions.Add(_yourWorkFlowTrackingClass);
_workflowApplication.Run();
```

You can also cast a TrackingRecord to a WorkflowInstanceRecord.  Between them, ActivityStateRecord and WorkflowInstanceRecord supply a lot of info about the workflow and its activities.

Comment: Your solution works as expected. Thanks a ton. I have posted below the complete source code which tracks all the workflows and activities.

Comment: Very pleased you got it to work.  Could you mark me as the answer if you can.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the following code which is able to track all the workflows and the activities.

```
public class ActivityTracker : TrackingParticipant
{
    protected override void Track(TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout)
    {            
        if (record != null)
        {
            if (record is WorkflowInstanceRecord)
            {
                WorkflowInstanceRecord instanceRecord = record as WorkflowInstanceRecord;
                Console.WriteLine("Workflow Record: Instance: {0} - State: {1} - Definition Identity: {2}", instanceRecord.ActivityDefinitionId, instanceRecord.State, instanceRecord.WorkflowDefinitionIdentity);
            }
            else if (record is ActivityStateRecord)
            {
                ActivityStateRecord instanceRecord = record as ActivityStateRecord;
                Console.WriteLine("Activity Record: Name: {0} - State: {1}", instanceRecord.Activity.Name, instanceRecord.State);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```